# Editing django admin css file does not load changes

Tags: css, django

I have made a small change to the base.css file in admin/css/base.css by changing an attribute "text-align: left;" to "text-align: center;" and saved it. The issue I have is when the css file is loaded in the browser, the attribute is still loaded as the original "text-align: left;". I have run the command "python manage.py collectstatic" and yet my changes are not reflected.

Any help regarding how to implement my changes will be most welcome. My main objective was using the django admin datepicker widget but I want to change that css attribute.

Comment: How are you serving your static files?

Comment: Did you clear your browser's cache? Are you reloading your page with `Shift + Ctrl + R`?

Comment: I have {% load static %} at the top of the template file and the specific css file is added using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}">

Answer (score 0):

do you have:

```
DEBUG = TRUE;
```

in your settings.py?

While in debug mode you can chose to load other static files.

So try it with:

```
DEBUG = FALSE;
```